# How to get the specific src of different image jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing the drag and drop web application. My problem is I can get the src of the first dragged element. But when I drag the second element, it will get the same src of the first element. I use `$(this).find(".drag").attr("src")` to get the src of image.

For example,

> drag the fist element src -> item_head/head45.png
>
> drag the second element src -> item_head/head45.png (but second
>   element src->item_head/head46.png )

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="options">
    <?php 
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM item_head ORDER BY ihead_id DESC";
       $objQuery = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
   ?>               
    <img width="150" height="120" src="item_head/<?php echo $row['filesName'];?>" id="drag1" class="drag"></img>
   <?php}?>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#frame").droppable({
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
                counter++;
                var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                element.addClass("tempclass");
                $(this).append(element);
                $(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
                $("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");
                //Get the dynamically item id
                draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
                itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1;
                var objsrc = $(this).find(".drag").attr("src");
                alert(objsrc);
                console.log(itemDragged)
                $("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
                var objtop  = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;

            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).find(".drag")` will not return a single element. Use `.last()`

```
$("#frame").droppable({
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            if (ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag[0-9]/) != -1){
                counter++;
                var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                element.addClass("tempclass");
                $(this).append(element);
                $(".tempclass").attr("id","clonediv"+counter);
                $("#clonediv"+counter).removeClass("tempclass");
                //Get the dynamically item id
                draggedNumber = ui.helper.attr('id').search(/drag([0-9])/)
                itemDragged = "dragged" + RegExp.$1;
                var objsrc = $(this).find(".drag").last().attr("src");
                alert(objsrc);
                console.log(itemDragged)
                $("#clonediv"+counter).addClass(itemDragged);
                var objtop  = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;

            }
        }
});
```

Comment: I cannot vote at this time, but I have already marked it  as correct answer. Thank you very very much to help me. It workkkkk!!!!